# how to integrate multiple push notifications for the same time & for the same app

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I just want to know is it possible to integrate multiple push notifications which fire at the same time & that is for the same time.

For example,

In skype if someone has texted me for the 5 times all 5 texts will be shown to me as a notification.

How this can be done with ios.
How to handle this? 
This can be done from client side or server side?

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: It's done by downloading all of the updates from the server.

Comment: yes  but how server will fire it for the same time?

Comment: How do you mean? The user triggers one push to open the app. The app gets all updates from the server (and clears the push notification list).

Comment: yes I can download all updates, but what my question is can server send multiple notifications for the same time?

Comment: You can try to send multiple pushes at the same time, there is always some latency of processing (and user annoyance at multiple notifications)

Answer (score 0):

http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-ios-push-notification-services-for-beginners .. Check if this is helpful ..  something for a beginner level ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.